# Graphql performance on data fetching

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I started looking into Sangria to create a Graphql server.

The first thing that is not clear to me, is how to fetch data in a large dataset context.
All examples work with fetching all the data from a database and then let Graphql do its thing. This feels like an inefficient way to fetch large amounts of data.

So how do you make Sangria scale? How do you optimize queries to not use a general select all?

Comment: Part of your graphql query definition should be parameters to scale down the amount of data collected. We use a limit + offset parameter so that the entire dataset is not selected nor returned.

Comment: How do you get these query parameters to your database query? Because in the examples they pass the query ast and the whole dataset to the executor.

Comment: Asked some more info at the gitter and found that I went over https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-akka-http-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/Data.scala too quickly. The resolver logic in there explains the solution :)